# Fill textboxes after record selected by drop down

Tags: php, textbox

How can I add to this dropdown some textboxes that will appear with information about the selected record?

```
 <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" id="customer_l"><?php echo $this->lang->line("customer"); ?></label>
    <div class="controls">  <?php
        $cu[""] = "";
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            if ($customer->company == "-" || !$customer->company) {
                $cu[$customer->id] = $customer->name . " (P)";
            } else {
                $cu[$customer->id] = $customer->company . " (C)";
            }
        }
        echo form_dropdown('customer', $cu, (isset($_POST['customer']) ? $_POST['customer'] : ""), 'id="customer_s"   data-placeholder="' . $this->lang->line("select") . ' ' . $this->lang->line("customer") . '" required="required" data-error="' . $this->lang->line("customer") . ' ' . $this->lang->line("is_required") . '"');
        ?> </div>
</div>
```

Any sugestion?
Thank you!

Comment: writing code would be a good start.

Comment: Put them in hidden DIVs. Then use Javascript that shows the appropriate DIV when you select something from the dropdown.